# how to search for html tag in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

i crawled site with apache nutch and indexed it to Apache Solr.i don't know how search strings between  and  html tags in a site with solr?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to extract data from the HTML and index extracted data. You can use the [HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory) to strip HTML from input stream.

```
<analyzer>
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```